# Convertir un archivo de texto en una lista

Tags: python, lista, archivo

Estoy intentando convertir un archivo de texto en una lista, usando Python.
El archivo de texto son muchas palabras, una abajo de la otra.

Lo que hice fue esto:

```
stop_words=open('stopwords.txt.txt','r') 

lineas = [linea.split() for linea in stop_words]

for linea in lineas:

      print(linea)
```

Pero lo que me imprime son muchas listas una abajo de la otra con una sola palabra. Y lo que yo quiero es una sola lista con todas las palabras, separadas por una coma.

Comment: gracias me ayudo con mi codigo

Answer (score 3):

[`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) lo que hace es tomar una cadena y dividirla en subcadenas usando el separador que se le pase como primer argumento. Si no se le pasa ningún separador se toma como tal a cualquier número de espacios consecutivos, eliminando también aquellos que se encuentren al principio y final de la cadena. Como la salida es una lista, lo que obtienes al aplicar `split` sobre cada línea es una lista de listas.

Si tal como dices, cada linea solo contiene una palabra, no necesitas `split` para nada, en todo caso si puedes necesitar [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)/`str.rstrip` para que elimine el salto de línea/retorno de carro y quedarte solo con la palabra:

```
with open('stopwords.txt.txt','r') as stop_words: 
    lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in stop_words]

for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)
```

Para un archivo como el siguiente:

> hola
>   mundo
>   python

obtendrás una lista como:

> ["hola", "mundo", "python"]

El método `str.strip` si no recibe argumentos elimina todos los espacios, tabulaciones, carácteres de nueva línea (\n) y retornos de carro (\r) tanto al principio como al final de la cadena.

Si quieres obtener una lista con las lineas en crudo (sin eliminar nada) puedes simplemente usar el método `readlines`:

```
lineas = stop_words.readlines()
```

Comment: Ahi pude! Muchisimas gracias

Comment: Dale ahi la acepto!

Comment: Tengo una duda mas.. Hice lo que me dijiste, pero al imprimir la lista, me la imprime 4 veces nose porque. Hay alguna forma de que solo me la imprima una sola vez?

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con que la imprime cuatro veces? Con el código que muestro no se imprime la lista sino cada elemento de esta (palabra) en una nueva línea. Si quieres imprimir la lista como tal no debes usar el `for`, simplemente `print(lineas)`. Si sigues con problemas puedes usar el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/118980/edit) que hay en tu pregunta para añadir tu problema actual al final de tu pregunta. Añade el código completo  tal y como lo tienes ahora, la salida que quieres y un ejemplo mínimo del txt si es posible, para poder reproducir el problema.

Comment: `readlines` es una mala sugerencia. Muy mala, de hecho. El desempeño es pobrísimo porque lee TODO el archivo antes de procesarlo. [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17246300/236345)

Comment: @Alfabravo no estaría de más ver la [implementación en CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f320be77ffb73e3b9e7fc98c37b8df3975d84b40/Modules/_io/iobase.c) de `readlines`... Simplemente usa `iobase_iternext` que a su vez usa la implemetación de `readline` para iterar sobre las líneas (igual que hace un `for in` sobre el fichero) y construye una lista con ellas, vamos básicamente como hacer `list(file)`...

Comment: Por supuesto que `readlines` es ineficiente  si quieres iterar sobre las líneas del archivo (hacer `for line in f.readlines()` es un sin sentido), pero el op pide una LISTA con las líneas del archivo no la forma más eficiente de iterar sobre ellas... En todo momento hablo de Python 3, dado que el código del op así lo parece y la ausencia de etiqueta. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

pues estuve revisando con este archivo de texto que tengo romeo.txt:

> ''' But soft what light through yonder window breaks It is the east
> and Juliet is the sun Arise fair sun and kill the envious moon Who is
> already sick and pale with grief '''

y utilicé el siguiente codigo con algunas modificaciones:

```
stop_words=open('romeo.txt','r')

lineas = [linea.split() for linea in stop_words]
total=list()
for linea in lineas: 
    total+=linea
print(total)
```

lo que imprimio fue lo siguiente:

```
['But', 'breaks', 'light', 'soft', 'through', 'what', 'window', 'yonder', 
 'It', 'Juliet', 'and', 'east', 'is', 'is', 'sun', 'the', 'the', 'Arise', 
 'and', 'envious', 'fair', 'kill', 'moon', 'sun', 'the', 'Who', 'already', 
 'and', 'grief', 'is', 'pale', 'sick', 'with']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
name_archivo=input("ingresar archivo:   ")
archivo=open(name_archivo)
lista=list()`
for linea in archivo:
    linea=linea.split()
    lista=lista+linea`
lista.sort()
print(lista)
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio. Gracias por tomar el tiempo en responder, pero colocar solo código se considera baja calidad. revisa [answer]